# Kusto: Query execution has exceeded the allowed limits (80DA0003):

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

There are three tables mentioned below, I eventually want to bring in a field from Table3 to Table1 (but the only way to join these two tables is via a common field present in Table2)

Table 1: Application Insights-30 days data (datasize ~4,000,000)
Table 2: Kusto based table (datasize: 1,080,153)
Table 3: Kusto based table (datasize: 38,815,878)

I was not able to join the tables directly, So, I used various filter conditions, distinct operators and split the month data to 4 weeks and then used union to join all 3 tables and got the resultant table.

However, now I am unable to perform any operations on the resultant table (even |count doesn't work)
I get the following error
`Query execution has exceeded the allowed limits (80DA0003):`

Any help in handling such cases would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please check article how to control the query limits:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-result-set-size-result-truncation

Answer (score 0):

When using the `join` operator, make sure that the table with fewer rows is the first one (left-most in query).
See more Best Practices [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices).